# How to create an Azure Subscription and Azure Active Directory programatically

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-resource-manager

I have a requirement to be able to create an Azure subscription and Azure AD Tenant programmatically (e.g with Terraform or an ARM Template etc - this part is not important, as long as I can find an API).

Looking at the [Azure RM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/apimanagementrest/azure-api-management-rest-api-subscription-entity#Prerequisites) it doesn't seem to be possible. Even the UI seems to redirect to a different app to create a subscription.

Any ideas on how to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar requirement on a project two years ago and we found **no way to programatically provision a subscription nor an Azure Active Directory**.

As far as I know, this is still not possible. However, we "solved" it by manually creating a pool of subscription and AAD and used them in our tenant boarding application.

Comment: Hmmm - not a bad solution if there is indeed no way of creating them - they would not be costing anything as they have no resources in them... thx